# Is android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE an explicit broadcast?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-manifest, android-8.0-oreo, android-download-manager

My app (targetSdk=25) has a broadcast receiver defined in the manifest as follows:

```
<receiver android:name="my.package.DownloadManagerReceiver"
     android:exported="true">
     <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE" />
     </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

My `DownloadManagerReceiver` is notified whenever Android's [DownloadManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager) finishes downloading a file, so I can do some processing on the file that was downloaded.

I'm working on migrating my app's targetSdk to 27 (Oreo). According to https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background#broadcasts, **implicit broadcast receivers registered through the manifest are not supposed to work in Android O** (except for those [whitelisted exceptions](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcast-exceptions)).

However, when I run my app using an emulator running Android 8.0 and targetSdk=27 **my broadcast receiver defined in the manifest is still notified** by the DownloadManager after a download completes.

I tried to find the source code where the DownloadManager sends its broadcast to understand how it sends its broadcasts but I couldn't find it.

Does anybody know whether `android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE` is an explicit broadcast rather than an implicit one? Any ideas why my receiver is still receiving that broadcast?

Answer (score 12):

Here's what I found after digging further into the platform's source code:

1) When we instantiate the DownloadManager, it keeps a reference to the context of the app and extracts the app's package name from that context

2) That package name is inserted into the downloads database into column  `Downloads.Impl.COLUMN_NOTIFICATION_PACKAGE` when the download is requested

3) When the download completes, the [DownloadInfo.sendIntentIfRequested()](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_packages_providers_downloadprovider/blob/161238418462a0b86e6037a188e56a78e48d814e/src/com/android/providers/downloads/DownloadInfo.java) method will call [Intent.setPackage()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#setPackage(java.lang.String)) passing the package name. According to the [description of method Intent.setPackage()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#setPackage(java.lang.String)):

> (Usually optional) Set an explicit application package name that
>   limits the components this Intent will resolve to. If left to the
>   default value of null, all components in all applications will
>   considered. If non-null, the Intent can only match the components in
>   the given application package.

Based on that description, my understanding is that the broadcast intent will be targeted at my app, thus working as an **explicit intent**.

Comment: Thanks for the investigation. We're currently in the very same situation, and just had another discussion about this topic. Based on your findings, I think we can avoid the effort of refactoring to a JobScheduler.