# Receiver for DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE in Manifest

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-download-manager

Is it possible to listen for `DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE` in Manifest.xml?

All the examples I found use `registerReceiver(downloadCompleteReceiver,new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));` from a `class` but I would like to receive it in Manifest.xml so I can listen when the app is closed. 
I can't find this action when I try to set the intent-filter for my receiver in Manifest.xml

Comment: It works, but you have to manually type in constant value: `android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE`.

Comment: @Pawel I have already tried that, it is not found.

Comment: Just because IDE does not autocomplete this value does not mean it won't work at runtime.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts) states:

> Beginning with Android 8.0 (API level 26), the system imposes additional restrictions on manifest-declared receivers.
>
> If your app targets Android 8.0 or higher, you cannot use the manifest to declare a receiver for most implicit broadcasts (broadcasts that don't target your app specifically). You can still use a [context-registered receiver](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts#context-registered-recievers) when the user is actively using your app.

From [Is android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE an explicit broadcast?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51674327/is-android-intent-action-download-complete-an-explicit-broadcast) we learn that `android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE` seems to be an explicit broadcast, therefore there should be no issue defining a `<receiver>` for it in the manifest, even if it's not autocompleted. So just add it with an action of `android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE`.

```
<receiver 
    android:name=".your.DownloadCompleteReceiver"
    android:permission="android.permission.SEND_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETED_INTENTS"
    android:exported="true">
  <intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```